# invalid syntax on quotation mark

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Why is this python script complaining about syntax?

```
  File "github-wiki-auditor.py", line 36
    print "[*] Exiting - {0} is not a valid accounts input file.".format(accountsFile)
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

full python script:
https://github.com/SmeegeSec/GitHub-Wiki-Auditor/blob/master/github-wiki-auditor.py

Comment: not sure this is it, but in python 3 'print' is a built-in function, so you can't use it like you do in python 2.7 ('print "somthing"'). you have to use brackets: 'print("somthing")'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the print function like in python 2.x on python 3.x just do

```
print("[*] Exiting - {0} is not a valid accounts input file.".format(accountsFile))
```